# Input Spark Dataframe to DeepLearning4J model

Tags: scala, apache-spark, deeplearning4j, nd4j

I've data in my `spark` `dataframe` (df) which have 24 features and the 25th column is my target variable. I want to fit my `dl4j` model on this `dataset` which takes input in the form of `org.nd4j.linalg.api.ndarray.INDArray,  org.nd4j.linalg.dataset.Dataset` or `org.nd4j.linalg.dataset.api.iterator.DataSetIterator`. How can I convert my `dataframe` to the required type ?

I've also tried using Pipeline method to input spark dataframe to the model directly. But sbt dependency of dl4j-spark-ml is not working. My build.sbt file is :

```
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies += "org.deeplearning4j" %% "dl4j-spark-ml" % "0.8.0_spark_2-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies += "org.deeplearning4j" % "deeplearning4j-core" % "0.8.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.nd4j" % "nd4j" % "0.8.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.nd4j" % "nd4j-native-platform" % "0.8.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.nd4j" % "nd4j-backends" % "0.8.0"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.0.1"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.0.1"
```

Can someone guide me from here ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use snapshots which have readded the spark.ml integration.
If you want to use snapshots, add the oss sonatype repository:
    https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/blob/master/dl4j-examples/pom.xml#L16
The version at the time of this writing is:
0.8.1-SNAPSHOT

Please verify the latest version with the examples repo though:
https://github.com/deeplearning4j/dl4j-examples/blob/master/pom.xml#L21

You can't mix versions of dl4j. The version you're trying to use is *very* out of date (by more than a year). Please upgrade to the latest version beyond that.

The new spark.ml integration examples can be found here:
https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/tree/master/deeplearning4j-scaleout/spark/dl4j-spark-ml/src/test/java/org/deeplearning4j/spark/ml/impl

Make sure to add the proper dependency, which is typically something like
org.deeplearning4j:dl4j-spark-ml_${YOUR SCALA BINARY VERSION}:0.8.1_spark_${YOUR SPARK VERSION (1 or 2}-SNAPSHOT

Comment: I've tried using `"org.deeplearning4j" %% "dl4j-spark-ml" % "0.8.0_spark_2-SNAPSHOT"` . But still its not working. I've edited my question with complete build.sbt file. Please check it once.

Comment: I said 0.8.*1*    Let me be more explicit:
 https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/org/deeplearning4j/dl4j-spark-ml_2.11/0.8.1_spark_2-SNAPSHOT/   It's definitely there. You shouldn't be running in to any problems.            
                 ^^^

Comment: I had to use `resolvers += "scala-tools.org" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/"` to make it work. Thanks for information. But what I want is to use - org.deeplearning4j.spark.ml.classification.NeuralNetworkClassification but it seems that this class is not available. Do you have any idea about it? All I want is to input my spark dataframe to the dl4j model.

Comment: That's..what this new release does? I'm a bit confused as to the problem here.https://github.com/deeplearning4j/deeplearning4j/blob/master/deeplearning4j-scaleout/spark/dl4j-spark-ml/src/test/java/org/deeplearning4j/spark/ml/impl/SparkDl4jNetworkTest.java#L42 Beyond that we're not and won't in the future support anything related to what you're looking at now. It's more than a year old. I can tell you this as the creator of deeplearning4j.